# Win10 Initial Setup Wizard - No Text Input Working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, setup

so I finally got around to reinstalling win10 on my girlfriends old(er) laptop just to refresh things.

Anyway, the install went well, but during the initial setup wizard (language, microsoft account, wifi, etc.) I am not able to input text into any of the fields. I can focus the field, but nothing inputs text into the field!

I went and temporarily made my wifi network open so I dont have to enter a password, but I get stuck on the part where I have to enter a local user account username. There is no way to enter text.

I have tried an external keyboard, as well as the onscreen keyboard. None of which worked.

I know the built-in keyboard works in general because when I alt+tab I get the window selection screen.

When I focus a text input field, however, I cannot enter any text.

Any idea how to get around this? Can I skip the initial setup wizard entirely? I pressed some random keys and was able to get a cmd prompt up, into whcih I could normally enter text. Its just these damn input fields in the setup wizard that dont seem to take any input.

Comment: Can you change a radio button with the Mouse?  Update BIOS on the machine. Then run DISM and SFC (even though you just installed).  Open an admin command prompt and run:  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth .  Follow with SFC /SCANNOW . When all is complete, restart and test

Comment: Have you tried recreating the installation media, the behavior you describe, is typically seen when there is a problem with the installation media itself.

Comment: I have not tried recreating the install media, I'll try that now first. @John I am able to change radio buttons with the mouse, for example on the accessibility options in the wizard

Comment: Try the steps I outlined above and also after that if need be run a Repair Install with the Media Creation Link.

Comment: Recreating the install media did the trick. Thanks guys!